# Laravel: What is the meaning and purpose of the { } operator?

Tags: php, laravel, loops, operators

Laravel: What is the meaning and purpose of the {  } operator? Is it Laravel specific or is it contained in php?

In the following code, `{  }` is used. What exactly is it, and what does it do?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$users = User::all();
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            Mail::raw("{$key} -> {$value}", function ($mail) use ($user) {
                $mail->from('info@web.com');
                $mail->to($user->email)
                    ->subject('Hello');
            });
```

Comment: It's a PHP syntax for embedding variables in double-quoted strings. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: String interpolation. You can actually omit them also, but some find it more readable with them. Variables inside of `"` will be evaluated, so given the variable `$bar = 'bar';`, using either `"foo-$bar"` or `"foo-{$bar}"` will both result in `"foo-bar"`. Variables inside of `'` aren't: See https://3v4l.org/qBn3B for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These means "variable variables". Eg `$mysqli->query` its the same like `${$aa}->{$bb}` when:

```
$aa = "mysqli";
$bb = "query";
```